# Turning a relation into a fact

Tags: prolog

I would like to ask a very basic question in prolog. I have a list of lists that looks like `[[a_1,a],[a_2,c],[a_3,e,f]]`. I would like to create a relation which gets that list and adds an infix to each one of those sublists. For example I would like to insert `x` as infix: `x([[a_1,a]),x([a_2,c]),x([a_3,e,f]])`.  The goal is to make the relation to be a fact. I was trying to use `findall` but without any success.

Example:

```
turn([[a_1,a],[a_2,c],[a_3,e,f]]).
```

Output:

```
[x([a_1,a]),x([a_2,c]),x([a_3,e,f])].
```

How to implement  it?

Comment: Upper case letters are variables, you need something like `[x(['A',a]),x(['B',c]),x(['D',e,f])].`

Comment: What do you mean by infix? `+` is an infix (operator) in `1+2`

Comment: @GuyCoder My bad, I fixed it. @false, probably the name is not good. Just trying to convert `[[a]]` to be `[x([a])]`. (I think its called a fact).

Comment: Of intrest: [assert/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=assert/1)

Answer (score 2):

`[x([a])]` is not, in and of itself, a *fact*. It's just a different Prolog *term* form. A *fact* is a term that is asserted in the database, doesn't represent a predicate, and can be queried. Sounds like you don't want to convert to "facts", but you just want to convert to a different term form.

It would be easy in this case with `maplist`:

```
turn_item(X, x(X)).

turn(TermList, NewTermList) :-
    maplist(turn_item, TermList, NewTermList).
```

Then:

```
| ?- turn([[a_1,a],[a_2,c],[a_3,e,f]], L).

L = [x([a_1,a]),x([a_2,c]),x([a_3,e,f])]

yes
```